# Мелкая страница при открытии с телефона

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, хостинг

мальчики. Я не умею программировать и плохо разбираюсь во всем этом. Не поможете? В общем я скопировала код страницы входа социальной сети "Вконтакте", выложила его на свой сайт. Проблема в том, что, если переходить через смартфон по ссылке с моим доменом, параметры страницы другие (уменьшенный сайт, нужно увеличивать с помощью касаний.) К вам следующий вопрос. Что делать? Мне нужно, чтобы сайт был нормальных размеров. Напишите мне, кто искренне хочет помочь.
Я ЭТИМ ИНТЕРЕСУЮСЬ В ОЗНАКОМИТЕЛЬНЫХ ЦЕЛЯХ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для начала надо знать, есть ли у сайта адаптив (чтобы на разных экранах смотрелось нормально, а не больше\меньше), если нету - то делать, заранее обсудив\сделав дизайн по различные устройства.

Comment: @De.Minov
А его сложно делать?

Comment: @АнастасияШевченко, зависит какой дизайн будет от "большого" до "маленького" экрана. В профиле (кликнув по моему нику) есть контакты для связи со мной, можете написать мне, я отвечу на вопросы.

Comment: @De.Minov
Ну, если переходить по компу, то все нормально, однако, если переходить через смартфон, то сайт маленький.  Подстраивать под мобилу сложно? Или ерунда?

Comment: @АнастасияШевченко, выше написал, зависит от дизайна по большей части.

Comment: Интересно, а кто уже человеку минусов наставил?

Comment: @De.Minov
А вот если скачать код мобильной версии вк и выложить на сайт, то сайт вовсе не открывается. В чем в принципе может заключаться проблема?

Comment: @Vanya228
Не знаю

Comment: @АнастасияШевченко, увы, никто не скажет почему, ибо сами не видим.

Comment: Так нравятся такие вопросы, а как парень которые не шарит спросить так сразу иди учи, читай и тд. закрыли вопрос. А тут и телефончик дали и помоготу в случае чего))

Comment: "скопировала код страницы входа социальной сети "Вконтакте", выложила его на свой сайт." Попахивает фишингом.

Comment: @u_mulde ну как бы да, но я это проверяю свои возможности. И все. Я ведь написала, что в ознакомительных целях и все

Comment: Лол, а мошенник написал бы "Конечно, мне для фишингового сайта надо"?

Comment: @u_mulde Лол, а душнила написал бы "попахивает фишингом*

Comment: @u_mulder  а что делать людям, которым просто интересно?

Comment: @De.Minov заходите на сайт m.vk.com нажимаете CTRL + S и все этот код. Когда вставляю этот код на свой сайт, то он не запускается

Comment: @Vanya228 спасибо)

Comment: @АнастасияШевченко, забудьте об этом способе. Многие моменты не будут работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy         Оу, спасибо)